# A function which satisfies $(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2 = 85$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For every thrice differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[-3,3]$ with $(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2 = 85$. Which of the following statement(s) is (are) TRUE?

(A) There exists $x_0\in(a,a+6)$ such that $(f'(x_0))^2\leq 1$.

(B) $(f'(x))^2$ can take all real values in the interval $(0, 76]$.

(C) There exists $\alpha\in(-6,0)$ such that $(f(\alpha))^2+(f'(\alpha))^2 = 10$.

(D) There exists $\alpha\in(-6,6)$ such that $|f(\alpha)|= |f''(\alpha)|$.

(E)  There exists atleast one $c\in(-3,3)$ such that $(f'(c))(f'''(c))<0$.

Answer: (ABCDE) i.e all options are correct.

**My observations:**
I was able to prove the first one using Lagrange’s Mean value theorem and some basic inequalities but wasn’t able to prove the rest.

$f'(0)$ cannot be zero as if it were zero then the value of $f(0)$ would go outside the given range

I tried to prove the third statement using statement 1. I think I came close but I had no clarity whatsoever. That is all I was able to do.

Comment: $f$ only takes values in $[-3,3]$, and so $f(0)^2\leq 9$ and $76\leq f'(0)^2$ and $f$ cannot be constant.

Comment: @spinosarus123. I came upto that point but was not able to proceed

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange Chirag, Pl format your question in mathjax for it to be in line with the standard here. , the rest looks OK!

Comment: Also, please include your work for the first option. Thanks!

Comment: @Buraian Could you please tell me how to format in mathjax? I've no clue

Comment: There is a site tour when you click ask the question button, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A first hint for Mathjax formatting is to enclose formulas between dollar signs like this for example `$(f '( x_0))^2 \le 1$`. A second one is that operators are prefixed by a backslash like here `c \in (a,a+6)` for operator "belongs to".

Answer (score 2):

I'll go ahead and give a partial answer for (B)-(D) here. Concerning (B), observe that for $x>0$, by the mean value theorem we have $\xi\in (0,x)$ with
$$
|f'(\xi)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{x}\leq \frac{6}{x}\overset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0,
$$
i.e. $f'(\xi)^2$ takes values arbitrarily close to $0$. Together with $f'(0)\geq 76$, as already noted in the comments, this implies the claim by the intermediate value theorem.

For (C), we have $x_0\in (-6, 0)$ with $f'(x_0)^2\leq 1$ by (A), which means $f(x_0)^2+f'(x_0)^2\leq 10$. Together with $f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=85$, the intermediate value theorem does the job.

Lastly, for (D) note that we have $x_0\in (-6, 0)$ and $x_1\in (0,6)$ with $$f(x_0)^2+f'(x_0)^2=f(x_1)^2+f'(x_1)^2=10$$ by (C) and moreover, $x_0$ and $x_1$ can be chosen so that $f'$ does not have a zero in the interval $(x_0, x_1)$.

(The last assertion is a bit tricky: If $f'$ does not have any zeroes in $[0,6]$, we automatically get no zeroes of $f'$ in $[0, x_1)$; however, if $f'$ does have zeroes in $[0,6]$ then the set $\{x\in [0,6]: f'(x)=0\}$ is bounded and closed (since it's the intersection of a closed set with a pre-image of a closed set under a continuous function), hence compact and nonempty, which means it has a minimum $m<\infty$. Then $f'(0)^2\geq 76$ and $f'(m)^2=0$ so that the intermediate value theorem gives $\xi\in (0, m)$ with $f'(\xi)=1$. This means $f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=85$ whereas $f(\xi)^2+f'(\xi)^2\leq 10$ and, once again by the intermediate value theorem, we obtain $x_1\in (0,\xi)$ with $f(x_1)^2+f'(x_1)^2=10$; moreover, by the choice of $x_1$, we have $x_1<m$ and hence $f'$ does not have any zeroes in $[0, x_1)$. Similarly, we can choose $x_0$ so that $f'$ does not have any zeores in $(x_0, 0]$, which finally gives what we wanted.)

With that out of the way, Rolle's theorem gives an $\alpha\in (x_0, x_1)$ where the derivative of $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ vanishes, i.e.
$$
0=2f(\alpha)f'(\alpha)+2f'(\alpha)f''(\alpha)=2f'(\alpha)\left(f(\alpha)+f''(\alpha)\right).
$$
Since $f'$ does not have any zeroes in $(x_0, x_1)$ by construction, we can divide by $2f'(\alpha)$ and obtain $f(\alpha)+f''(\alpha)=0$. In particular, $|f(\alpha)|=|f''(\alpha)|$, as desired.

I have no idea how to prove assertion (E), though. I can probably prove that there is some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f'(c)f'''(c)\leq 0$, but have no idea how to get it to work for $c\in (-3, 3)$. I'd love to see part (E) answered by someone else!

Comment: But we already proved or at least if we assume B to be correct, (f′(x))^2 can only approach 0 but never take the value 0. So we could easily divide by f'(alpha) right?

Comment: (B) just asks you to prove that $f'(x)^2$ can take any value in $(0, 76]$ - however, you are not asked to prove (and what I wrote above does not prove this) that $f'(x)^2$ cannot take any other values besides those in $(0,76]$. I.e., it might well be that $f'(x)^2$ is zero for some $x$ and it might just as well be greater than $76$ for some $x$ - part (B) does not make any statement about that whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad I thought (f′(x))^2 is restricted to take values between (0,76]. Thanks a lot for your help!!